# Font looks weird on iPhone web

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, fonts

I am loading the Open Sans Google font using:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

It loads and looks greate on my PC, however, when I open the website on my iPhone using Safari the font looks very weird, different from the one I see on my PC.
This font is loaded using Google fonts so it should show up on my mobile website too I assume.

This is how I set the font in CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

**iPhone:**

[image]

**PC:**

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the space between individual letters?

Comment: Also, I don't see you exporting any additional font weights from Google but that looks like a rather heavy font. If you're unintentionally forcing the font to fake a heavier weight it could lead to issues.

Comment: What browser do you use in PC?

Comment: Try add this at your css code `* { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }` and see if there is any different.

Comment: I am talking about the look of each letter.

Comment: I loaded the regular font and put it as a bold weight.
The browser I use on my PC is Chrome.

Comment: I added the smoothing and the bold version of the font, still the same.